# Spherical vs. Exponential Kriging Covariance Functions

Tags: variogram, kriging

A statistical epidemiologist colleague of mine told me that in comparing spherical vs exponential kriging covariance functions, only the latter (i.e., exponential) function is generally a valid model.

Most papers I have read compare spherical vs. exponential covariance functions in relation to semivariogram fitting using estimates of the the nugget, range and sill parameters.

In my work, I am using kriging as a smoothing method via Generalized Additive Models (GAMs) in the **mgcv** R package.

I was just wondering if it would be better to choose between these two covariance functions when fitting GAMs, rather than having to fit both. **mgcv** does not have variogram fitting functions, so one must rely on other packages such as **GeoR**.

Comment: If I remember correctly, your colleague is correct in three or more dimensions (where the spherical model might not be positive definite) but they are certainly wrong in two dimensions. The proof is that the spherical model is simply the overlap integral of two uniform disks centered at each point, which makes it obvious it will be positive semi-definite.

Comment: Thanks. The R documentation for 'mgcv' speaks to using a simple form of the covariance function from the Matern family, suggested by Kammann and Wand (2003). I only recently came across this paper, but perhaps their suggesting of covariance function is widespread for GAM smoothing; whereas, spherical and exponential functions are more widely employed for variogram analysis?

Comment: The Matern family has been around decades longer than that: Matern published it in his [1960 thesis](https://pub.epsilon.slu.se/10033/1/medd_statens_skogsforskningsinst_049_05.pdf).  It's used in `geoRglm` for variography.